# Сбивается кодировка при компиляции Java-файлов

Tags: java, кодировка, swing, netbeans

Итак, я решился изучать Java (Использую среду NetBeans). Сначала всё работало хорошо, в консоль символы выводились нормально, когда я писал несложные программки в стиле "Hello World!". Но вот я решил покопаться в теме создания приложений с графическим интерфейсом, используя библиотеки "swing" и "awt". При компиляции и выполнении появляется окно, но вместо кириллицы непонятные символы (типа Р­С‚Р° РєРЅРѕРїРєР° Р·Р°РєСЂС‹РІР°РµС).
Я пробовал как запуск через сам NetBeans, так и компиляцию и выполнение через командную строку - результат одинаковый. В NetBeans уже выставлял кодировку windows-1251. Как понимаете, не помогло.
Если так надо, вот код класса с окном, где и находится текст на кириллице:

```
package myinterface;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Frame extends JFrame {
    Frame() {
        super("Окно с кнопкой :)");
        setBounds(250, 250, 300, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Эта кнопка закрывает окно");
        lbl.setBounds(10, 30, 280, 50);
        add(lbl);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Закрыть окно");
        btn.setBounds(50, 120, 200, 30);
        MyHandler hnd = new MyHandler();
        btn.addActionListener(hnd);
        add(btn);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, какая кодировка у файла Frame.java. Если работаете из под linux или maс, то сделать это можно с помощью команды `file -i путь/до/Frame.java`

Comment: @Vadik, к сожалению, у меня Windows. Есть способы посмотреть кодировку на этой ос? (в свойствах файла нет, в интернете тоже не нашел)